# conditional non-delegated jQuery UI tooltip

Tags: jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

Is it possible to create and display an *ad hoc* jQuery UI tooltip, from with a particular TD element's `mouseenter` eventhandler, conditionally, if the value of the cell is above a certain amount, say? The code would test the cell's value and instantiate and display the tooltip after 500ms had elapsed, and close the tooltip in the `mouseleave`. By "ad hoc" I mean without having attached the tooltip to a selector in the `document.ready` section.

EDIT: The reason for my question: is there a significant memory or processing overhead to attaching a tooltip to every cell in a large table, when only a few of the cells would actually meet the conditions where  a tooltip would be opened?